# Photoshop TonTon scripts by Michel Mariani - usage and difference to xtools

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-scripting, actions, javascript, extended-scripting

Anyone uses the Michel Mariani TonTon JSON scripts in Photoshop 2023 / 2024? How to install the jsxinc? When I rename it to jsx, they will show in PS. I have tested the action utility to convert an atn to json. But there are four checkboxes, I don´t know to use these. And what´s the difference between the tonton scripts to xtools? special for atn conversion.

Are both converters uptodate with newer versions? There are many new functions in PS23 since the building date of these scripts.

And what about the tonton action manager? How to install it?

Perhaps it´s easier to run a automatic conversion job for disable all Dialogs inside an action with the tonton ATN converter script? ALL means also the filter prompts.

I tried the tonton scripts with a renaming of filenames. JSXINC won´t automaticly show in scripts menu.